# msi installer customer information form validate license

Tags: windows-installer

I am creating a setup project for a windows application where I have added customer information form with license key to enter, now I would like to make api call for this license and validate it against the database value and if it was validate I need to continue installation. Is there any possibility to do this I have gone through the custom actions but didn't get how to proceed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***Custom Action***: You need to use a custom action to do custom logic like that, but those are complicated and you expose a license validation method that is easy to crack I suppose.

***Application Launch***: Please have a read of: [**`Reasons to put license validation in the application and not the setup`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24360658/129130). There are many reasons to eliminate complexity in the form of custom actions from setups for reliability-reasons. [Please skim this propaganda against custom actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179778/why-is-it-a-good-idea-to-limit-the-use-of-custom-actions-in-my-wix-msi-setups/46179779#46179779) (at least the first summary section).

***Overall***: Application code is easy to debug, custom actions are VERY exotic to learn to do right - due to complex `sequencing-`, `conditioning-` and `impersonation` issues and overall poor debugability. ***`In the application you are in a familiar debugging context. VERY important`***.

---

***Getting started with Visual Studio Installer Projects***: Here is a good, but age-old article with a section on custom actions: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/ - and [here is one more from CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335516/Custom-Action-in-Visual-Studio-setup-projects) and [a third one](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-perform-custom-actions-and-upgrade-using-visual-studio-installer/).

***Alternatives***: Why you should not rely on Visual Studio Installer Projects for serious setups (IMHO): [Visual Studio Publish Project Into One Simple Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936435/visual-studio-publish-project-into-one-simple-installer/47944893#47944893) ([Painter's nice condensed-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635671/why-use-windows-installer-xml-wix-over-vdproj/2637666#2637666)).

- [Here is a quick list of other deployment tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130)
- [WiX quick-start suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)