# Install a windows service with InstallUtil.exe command during an installation

Tags: c#, installation, installutil

I've a `Console Application` project in a `Visual Studio Solution`. This application, called here for semplicity MyApplication.exe, is nothing but an host of a WCF Service.

I need an installer for install my application on the target machine, so I download the `Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects` extension. I collected all the files I want to be copied into the Application Folder but I want that the installer even registers my service as a Windows Service.

For this goal, I imported the `InstallUtil.exe` just like shown on the below picture. I created the nested extra folders (Windows Folder -> Microsoft.NET -> Framework64 -> v4.030319) in order to reflect the actual structure of the target environment.

[image]

Then I created the `Custom Action` like this under the `Commit` node:

[image]

with the following `Arguments:`

> "[TARGETDIR]MyApplication.exe"

I tried the generated setup and I noticed that all the files are copied but the service is not installed (I don't see it on the MSC list).

So, below my questions:

- Where and what am I doing wrong?
- Is there any log I can check?
- In which way I can uninstall the service, if it was already installed previously?
- Frankly speaking, I expected something more customizable.. For example additional checkbox related to my application or something that the user can manage at installation time. If my `App.config` contains a KeyValue [Server="localhost"] is there a way to customize it at installation time with a popup to the user: 'Where is your server?" and update my config file with the information prompted by the user?

Answer (score 0):

***Limits***: [Visual Studio Installer Projects have many limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936435/visual-studio-publish-project-into-one-simple-installer/47944893#47944893) ([short version, Chris Painter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2637666/129130)).

***Alternative Tools***: [There are many other tools, some of which are free](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130).

---

> ***WiX Toolkit***: The WiX Toolkit is free and open source. Here are two examples of how to install services without the need to run custom
>   actions (the ability to install services is built-in to MSI, no need
>   to use **`InstallUtil.exe`** - [the "say no" to unnecessary custom action campaign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46179779/129130)):
>
> - [Rainer Stropek's WiX Service Installer sample](https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/blob/master/WiXSamples/WindowsService/ServiceInstaller/Product.wxs)
>
>   - [Top level, with service exe code too](https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/tree/master/WiXSamples/WindowsService)
> - https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials/tree/master/windows-service

---

***Links***:

- [Here are many links on WiX and other topics related to deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will be useful to someone in a similar situation.

**Using Statement**

```
using System.Configuration.Install;
```

**Installing**

```
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
```

**Uninstalling**

```
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
```

The above handles the functionality for the InstallUtil you've mentioned.

**Documentation**

[ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.install.managedinstallerclass.installhelper?view=netframework-4.8)

[Documentation on InstallUtil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/installutil-exe-installer-tool)

**The utility is located in the following places:**

.NET directories on a Windows system:

- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v \InstallUtil.exe
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v \InstallUtil.exe

InstallUtil.exe is digitally signed by Microsoft.